# KVM bridged network like in virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, opensuse

I have a server with 3 NIC's with OpenSUSE 13.2 and KVM installed. I have installed Debian as guest.

My network is `192.168.88.0/24`, DHCP server is at `192.168.88.1`. Now I want my guest to also get a `192.168.88.x` IP-address from the DHCP server. This behaviour is possible with VirtualBox using "Bridged networking".

I found this page about networking in KVM: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking. User Networking, private virtual bridge and public virtual bridge isn't what I want.

I instead used "Virtual network defualt: NAT". Now my VM is getting an IP, but `192.168.122.x`.

How can I give the VM an IP in the same range as the host os, without loosing the IP of the host os?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I found out what I was doing wrong. I was creating the network in bridge in `YAST`, the configuration tool for OpenSUSE. However you should (of course..) create the network bridge in the `virt-manager` tool:

[image]

Inside this window I can configure everything I want. You can also configure the network interfaces themself

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want the public bridge option. On your OpenSUSE KVM host the IP address moves from the physical NIC to the bridge interface and keeps it accessible on your `192.168.88.0/24` network and your Debian guest virtual NIC is connected through the bridge which also makes it attached to the same local network.

Using the NAT default means your Debian guest is effectively hidden behind the OpenSUSE KVM host and uses a private `192.168.122.0/24` network for any direct communication between each other but when communicating with other hosts on your network is NAT'd to whatever IP the OpenSUSE host has.

Comment: But then I can't acces my OpenSUSE KVM via ssh/ICMP etc?

Comment: @LEDfan Why would that be the case? The public bridge _is_ what you want.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not sure, but the KVM host lost his public IP, so how can I connect with it?

Comment: @LEDfan What are you talking about?

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong, see my answer.